# Is there an undubbed version of Hercules (1983)?

Tags: alternate-version, dubbing, hercules-1983

Is there an undubbed version of [Hercules (1983)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085672/?ref_=nv_sr_5) in which you hear Lou Ferrigno's original voice?